# Equivalent Conditions for a Prime to not Contain Conductor

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I am working through some notes on algebraic number theory, and am trying to show the following five conditions are equivalent. Here, $A\subset B$ is an extension of Dedekind domains corresponding to a field of fractions extension $K\subset L$, and $O$ is an order of $B$ (in particular, a Noetherian domain with Krull dimension 1, with integral closure $B$ in $L$). $\mathfrak{c}$ is the conductor of $O$ in $B$, so the largest ideal of $B$ that is contained in $O$, and $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal. The conditions are:

1. $\mathfrak{p}$ does not contain $\mathfrak{c}$.
2. $O=\{x\in B:x\mathfrak{p}\subset\mathfrak{p}\}$.
3. $\mathfrak{p}$ is invertible as a fractional ideal.
4. $O_\mathfrak{p}$ is a DVR.
5. $\mathfrak{p}O_\mathfrak{p}$ is a principal ideal.

I believe I understand all the equivalences except for (1)<->(2), where I cannot show that (2) implies (1).

Answer (score 1):

See Theorems 3.1, 3.4, and 6.1 [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/conductor.pdf).  The context there is orders in number fields, but you should be able to extend the arguments to the more general setting you are considering.